# How to convert Dictionary<XElement,XElement> into xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary, xelement

> Dictionary

```
Dictionary<XElement, XElement> _XParents = new Dictionary<XElement, XElement>();
```

> My dictionary looks like:

```
key:<node>, value:<parentNode>
```

**I want to convert this dictionary to XML file**

> XML should look like:

```
<parentNode>
    <node/>
</parentNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            XElement root = new XElement("Root");

            foreach (XElement _XParent in _XParents.Keys)
            {
                root.Add(_XParent);
            }
```

Your dictionary key should be a string so code should look like this

```
            Dictionary<string, XElement> _XParents = new Dictionary<string, XElement>();

            XElement root = new XElement("Root");

            foreach (string _XParent in _XParents.Keys)
            {
                root.Add(new XElement(_XParent, _XParents[_XParent]));
            }
```

Comment: I can not change the dictionary data type I have to use dictionary<XElement, XElement>

Comment: It will not work.  The keys will be different for each XElement and will include all the children.  To get the string of the key you can use LocalName.Name.